# Linq query with Nested Objects too slow

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq

I have a linq query in code that looks something like below

```
var results = Obj1.Obj2withinObj1.Icollection_Obj3withinObj2
  .Where(s => s.obj4withinobj3.obj5withinobj4 != null)
  .Select(s => s.obj4withinobj3.obj5withinobj4)
  .SelectMany(s => s.IenumStringwithinobj5)
  .Count();
```

This query performs extremely slowly and crashes which i am trying to fix.  This does return a lot of records  from sql server

Questions
1.This queries sql server but what is this  Entityframwork or Linqtosql.
2.  what part of the code runs on sql server and what part in memory. Does SelectMany run in memory and rest on sqlserver. Again how can i tell this myself.
3. How can I make this query faster.Would indexes on Db help?

Comment: It is a not a valid LINQ query, so no help. Better to examine generated SQL.

Comment: i am using sql profiler to find the query it runs in the backend. It is running a bunch of Select queries from all the underlying tables. But I cannot find one big select statement with all the joins. Is that possible?

Comment: if it is EF 6 - it is almost impossible. Examine which navigation properties are used (Tables) often and search for query by these properties.
With EF Core, you can tag all complex queries https://learn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/ef/core/querying/tags

Comment: i made a small change to the Linq. Obj3 is a icollection within obj2. Now I hope the linq makes sense?

Comment: I've edited your question and for now it is more clear. `Obj1.Obj2withinObj1.Icollection_Obj3withinObj2` what is it? it is IQueryable?

Comment: it is a Icollection. I am not sure if it is Iqueryable. It extends from a Wrapper class(wrapper is a just a abstract class) .Obj1 , Obj2withinObj1  ,  Icollection_Obj3withinObj2  ,    obj4withinobj3 are all table in database. Sorry if I am unable to answer correctly. Also I am not sure why my sql profiler just shows Select to Obj2withinObj1  and Icollection_Obj3withinObj2   only when i debug this statement in vs..

Answer (score 1):

The evidence that you're running a statement like:

```
var results = Obj1.Obj2withinObj1.Icollection_Obj3withinObj2....
```

and your profiler is showing a lot of `Select` statements against the related tables points to this being a lazy load hit.

For example, if you have:

```
var obj1 = dbContext.Object1s.Where(/* ... */).Single();
```

then go:

```
var results = obj1.Obj2withinObj1.Icollection_Obj3withinObj2....
```

EF has executed the query with the first statement on the `Single` call. Any attempts to access collections etc. on Obj1 will result in lazy load operations to load *all* related entities rather than query across them.

Option 1:  Deal with `IQueryable`

```
var query = dbContext.Object1s.Where(/* ... */); // No Single/FirstOrDefault etc.
var results = query.Obj2withinObj1.Icollection_Obj3withinObj2....
```

This should defer execution until you do your `SelectMany`. Generally I advise using `IQueryable` as much as possible but you have to be careful as everything in the expression has to be able to bubble down to SQL to work properly. This means no private/static methods, limits to some type interpretation methods / casting, and no access to unmapped properties in expressions. EF6 and EFCore 3+ will throw exceptions if you attempt to do something that needs to be executed in memory. EFCore 2 would automatically pre-execute and switch to Linq2Object (with a warning emitted) which could hide this issue as a poorly performing operation.

Option 2: Eager load related entities

```
var obj1 = dbContext.Object1s
   .Include(x => x.Obj2withinObj1)
       .ThenInclude(x => x.Icollection_Obj3withinObj2)
   /* ... */
   .Where(/* ... */).Single();
```

Then...

```
var results = obj1.Obj2withinObj1.Icollection_Obj3withinObj2....
```

By eager loading everything in one hit you avoid the various lazy loading calls and execute one query with Joins. This will still end up being more expensive than option 1, but faster than lazy loading.

Comment: This was extremely helpful and thanks for explaining this so well..However need some more help in finding the fix. I have modified the linq and added a Count() function in the end which i had missed earlier. For me Opt 2 seems feasible. Obj1 in my case is coming from a foreach loop that loops through a Icollection of obj1. I tried changing the foreach loop to simple for loop and accessed the obj1 like object1s.ElementAt(counter).Obj2withinObj1.Icollection_Obj3withinObj2.. ...Count() remaining LINQ was same . but profiler made multiple select statements again. How to make this eager load?

Comment: Since object1s.ElementAt(counter).Include-> does not work on icollections

Comment: If Obj3 has linked objects or collections you can chain additional `.ThenInclude()` to eager load those. If Obj2 has additional dependencies (other than `Collection<Obj3>`, I.e. also has a `Collection<Obj4>` then you add `.Include(x => x.obj2).ThenInclude(x => x.Obj4s)` (it will look like Obj2 is included twice in the statement but that's how it resolves multiple dependencies.) Eager loading is applied before Obj1(s) are materialized. Ultimately to narrow it down further we'd need to see exactly what you're loading and what you want to get out of it.